# Sort JavaScript Array based on Key Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have an array of Objects with status 'Pass' & 'Fail'. I want to move all Fail one's at the top and Pass one's at Bottom. Is there any array method to do the same?

```js
let a = [
  { name: 'x'  , status: 'Pass' },
  { name: 'x1' , status: 'Fail' },
  { name: 'x2' , status: 'Pass' },
  { name: 'x3' , status: 'Fail' }
];
```

Required Output is

```js
a = [
  { name: 'x1' , status: 'Fail' },
  { name: 'x3' , status: 'Fail' },
  { name: 'x'  , status: 'Pass' },
  { name: 'x3' , status: 'Pass' }
];
```

Comment: Create two arrays. One for failed values and one for pass values. Then combine the two.

Comment: I edited your code formatting, and noticed an extra `x3` key, and a missing `x2`. Was this intentional? I assume that the second `x3`  should probably be an `x2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idiomatic solution for this task:

```js
[...a.filter(el=>el.status==='Fail'),...a.filter(el=>el.status==='Pass')]
```

However, I thinq @farooq's solution is the best here

Answer (score 2):

If you are just sorting lexicographically, simply use `localeCompare`, and logical-OR the status and name comparison values.

```js
let data = [
  { name: 'x'  , status: 'Pass' },
  { name: 'x1' , status: 'Fail' },
  { name: 'x2' , status: 'Pass' },
  { name: 'x3' , status: 'Fail' }
];

const sorted = data.sort(
  ({ name: n1, status: s1 }, { name: n2, status: s2 }) =>
    s1.localeCompare(s2) || n1.localeCompare(n2))

console.log(sorted);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    let failed = []
    let passed = []
       for(let i = 0; i < values.length; i++){ 
         if(values[i].pass){
            passed.push(values[i])
         else {
            failed.push(values[i])
          }
       }
values = []
values.push(...failed)
values.push(...passed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function to sort your array of objects.
code :

```js
let a = [
      {
        name: "x",
        status: "Pass",
      },
      {
        name: "x1",
        status: "Fail",
      },
      {
        name: "x2",
        status: "Pass",
      },
      {
        name: "x3",
        status: "Fail",
      },
    ];
    a.sort(function (a, b) {
      var keyA = a.status,
        keyB = b.status;
      // Compare the 2 values
      if (keyA < keyB) return -1;
      if (keyA > keyB) return 1;
      return 0;
    });
    console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Ascii Value you can sort arrays as well

```
a.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.status > b.status ? 1 : a.status < b.status ? -1 : 0;
});
```

Comment: why not `a.status>b.status`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do this with `Array#sort` and `String#localeCompare` methods.

```js
const a = [ { name: 'x', status: 'Pass' }, { name: 'x1', status: 'Fail' }, { name: 'x2', status: 'Pass' }, { name: 'x3', status: 'Fail' } ],

      output = a.sort(
          ({status:x},{status:y}) => x.localeCompare(y)
      );
      
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) combined with [`String.localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) as follows:

```js
let a = [
  { name: 'x'  , status: 'Pass' },
  { name: 'x1' , status: 'Fail' },
  { name: 'x2' , status: 'Pass' },
  { name: 'x3' , status: 'Fail' }
];

const result = a.sort((o1, o2) => o1.status.localeCompare(o2.status));

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use forEach

```js
let failed = []
let passed = []
values = [
  { name: 'x'  , status: 'Pass' },
  { name: 'x1' , status: 'Fail' },
  { name: 'x2' , status: 'Pass' },
  { name: 'x3' , status: 'Fail' }
]

values.forEach((e) => {
  if (e.status === 'Pass') {
    passed.push(e)
    return
  }
  failed.push(e)
})

values = []
values.push(...failed)
values.push(...passed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to use this way, using very simple Javascript functions `unshift` and `push`, widely compatible to all kinds of browsers.

```js
let a = [
  { name: 'x'  , status: 'Pass' },
  { name: 'x1' , status: 'Fail' },
  { name: 'x2' , status: 'Pass' },
  { name: 'x3' , status: 'Fail' }
];

let b = [];
for(var x in a ) {
  if(a[x].status == 'Fail') { b.unshift(a[x]); } else { b.push(a[x]); }
}
console.log(b);
```